# Converting mgz to img in freesurfer?

Tags: neuroscience

I have spm files in nii that I've converted to mgz, but I need in img to co-register in spm (I think?)

Ultimately, I just want to cortically project my spm images (https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/SpmPainting)

Does anyone know how to convert in freesurfer? I am trying to use the mriconvert but it says it can't read my file!

Comment: If no luck on this site, our [bioinformatics.se] stack may be of some use to you, now or in the future.